# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^r \exp(-k\sum_1^n \frac{1}{m})$ convergent when $k>r$ and $r<k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^r \exp(-k\sum_1^n \frac{1}{m})$$

The problem is asked to investigate this series when $r>k$ and $r<k$.

However:

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\approx 1+\frac{r-k}{n}
$$

I thought when $r-k<-1$ this series will be convergent, not $r<k$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note 
$$ \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m} = \log n + \gamma + \varepsilon_n,$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler constant, $\lim \varepsilon_n = 0$.
Hence the general term is
$$n^r \exp(-k(\log n + \gamma + \varepsilon_n)) = \exp(-k(\gamma + \varepsilon_n))\frac{1}{n^{k - r}} \sim \exp(-k\gamma)\frac{1}{n^{k - r}}.$$
Therefore the series converges when $k - r > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

[Gauss's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Higher_order_tests)  asserts that for a positive series with terms $a_n$, if the ratio of successive terms

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1+\frac{h}{n}+\frac{B(n)}{n^{\alpha}}$$

where $\alpha>1$ and $B(n)$ is bounded as $n\to \infty$, then the series converges if $h>1$ and diverges otherwise.

For the problem of interest,

$$\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}=1+\frac{k-r}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\text{Thus, the series converges for}\,\, k-r>1 \,\,\text{and diverges otherwise.}}$$

Comment: Thank you. This is the canonical way of attacking this kind of problem. The other answer however is more interesting.

Comment: @buzhidao Well, you're welcome.  I was addressing your specific question.  You asked if you were right, and using your approach, I presented the way forward along with a reference of Gauss's law.  I would have been happy to present another way too.